# how to scan all usages of a custom function in all my php files?

Tags: php, file, function

I have created my own `l($text)` function in php for a multi lingual website. i use it like this in my documents :

```
echo '<h1>' . l('Title of the page') . '</h1';
echo '<p>' . l('Some text here...') . '</p>';
```

My question is, with a php script, how can i scan all my `.php` files to catch all this function usages and list all the arguments used into a mysql table?
the goal, of course, is to not forget any sentences in my traduction files.

I didn't find anything on google or here, so if you have any ideas, or need some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just finished, your help was usefull ! :-)

here is my ugly code for those who can be interested. it's not beautifuly coded, but not made to be loaded 10000 times per day so...

```
<?php
// define a plain text document to see what appen on test
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

$dossier = 'pages/'; // folder to scan
$array_exclude = array('.', '..', '.DS_Store'); // system files to exclude
$array_sentences_list = array();

if(is_dir($dossier)) // verify if is a folder
{
    if($dh = opendir($dossier)) // open folder
    {
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) // scan all files in the folder
        {
            if(!in_array($file, $array_exclude)) // exclude system files previously listed in array
            {
                echo "\n".'######## ' . strtoupper($file) . ' ##########'."\n";
                $file1 = file('pages/'.$file); // path to the current file
                foreach($file1 AS $fileline)
                {
                    // regex : not start with a to z characters or a (
                    // then catch sentences into l(' and ')
                    // and put results in a $matchs array
                    preg_match_all("#[^a-z\(]l\('(.+)'\)#U", $fileline, $matchs);

                    // fetch the associative array
                    foreach($matchs AS $match_this)
                    {
                        foreach($match_this AS $line)
                        {
                            // technique of "I do not want to break my head"
                            if(substr($line, 0, 3) != "l('" AND substr($line, 0, 4) != " l('" AND substr($line, 0, 4) != ".l('")
                            {
                                // check if the sentence is not already listed
                                if(!in_array($line, $array_sentences_list))
                                {
                                    // if not, add it to the sentences list array and write it for fun !
                                    $array_sentences_list[] = $line;
                                    echo $line . "\n";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

small precision : i do have to escape various cases as :
-> CSS : background: url('image.jpg');
and
-> jQuery : $(this).html('bla bla');
so here is why the regex starts with [^a-z(] :-)

it works very well now! just have to finish later with recording entries in a mysql table and ensure that i can load the script from time to time when there are changes on the site... keep the existing translation, overwrite the existing files etc... no problem with that.

thanks a gain, this website is really helpful ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you:

- read all *.php files with glob()
- then use a regex to pull the strings out (preg_match())
- strings simple mysql insert?

Seems simple enough?

Comment: hi andrew,
so my regex have to search for content between (' and ') ? i have to try this, will mark the question as answered if it's work, thanks ! :-)

Comment: Yeh. I would make it search between l(' and '). Something like /l\\('(.*?)'\\)/smi